Is it possible to call Key vault URI from config file to fetch the secret?
I came across a link which shows how to fetch the secret from the Azure Key vault.
It looks like, by just adding uri in the config file can fetch the secret from the AKV. Is it like, we don't have to write single line .net code? Is this another simple way to fetch the secret ? This is something I'm looking for the first time. Is there any example code available to help to understand and implement this way?

KeyVault URI works only with Azure App Service Environment variables.It will not work locally.

Refer this SOThread once.

Is this another simple way to fetch the secret ? - Yes


Is it possible to call Key vault URI from config file to fetch the secret?

You can retrieve the secrets with the KeyVault Reference for Azure App Service,it will not work locally.

To work locally add the secrets in Environment Variables.

For Azure App Service, Add the KeyVault reference in the Environment variables Section(App Setting/Connection String).



For .NET Framework apps check my SOThread
For .NET Core:
You can retrieve either with Environment Variable or using IConfiguration.
@inject IConfiguration myconfig
 KeyVault Secret - @Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TestKey")
 Sample Key - @myconfig["TestKey"]

Output:


Please can I get the MSFT official documentation to support this approach (via Environment variable )? Logically seems good. But, I'm not getting official MSFT link on this. Thanks.

Here is the MSDoc

@AskMe - Good to accept the solution if it has solved the problem. This is for the benefit of the SO Community, refer SO Link
